# How can a Chat bot mention a user that is not yet in the room?

Tags: google-apps-script, chatbot

I am trying to build a chatbot that will invite a user in a room where the Bot already is, but not yet the user.

- User wants to join Room A
- User DM the Bot and ask "invite me to Room A"
- Bot, already in room A, mentions User
- User is pulled in the room.

Currently, my bot can start a thread and mention a user, but the mention will work (showing `@Username`) only if Username is already in the room.
If Username is not in the room, it will show `<users/1234....>`.

Is there a way to do that?
Or in general, can a bot invite a user in a room?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Explanation: If you refer to [Bot access to user data](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/bots#bot_access_to_user_data) you'll find that -

In order to operate in a useful way, a bot needs to know who is invoking it, and how to address that person. Beyond this basic identity data, **bots do not have access to user data unless granted explicitly by the user**:

- By default, bots can only read the basic identity of users that invoke them. This information includes the user's display name, user ID, email address, and avatar image.
- If a bot needs to access other data to do its job, it can prompt the user to grant it additional access.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The bot has access to the user data. The flow is the following: User wants to join Room A > User DM the Bot and ask "invite me to Room A" > Bot, already in room A, mentions User > User is pulled in the room. The problem is that the user mention does not work if the user is not in the room.

Comment: Understood. In that case, its not just the bot, its the user as well. Currently, rooms are not publicly available for everyone in the domain. Users need to have access to a room either individually or through groups. Otherwise, even without a bot, users can't find or join rooms that they're not already a part of.

Comment: The curious thing is that it works if I, as a user, type @Username. Username is in fact allowed to join the room if I mention or invite them. But a bot cannot mention them.

Comment: Yes, that's true. A user can mention another user by @Username; however, the other user cannot find and join a room if they're not already a part of it either via default or by association (groups).